# IBM MobileFirst - Application Authenticity Public Key extraction

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

To enable the Application Authentication security feature I have to extract the public signing key as documented here:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_ibm_worklight_app_authentication_overview.html

My problem is that the wizard from MobileFirst Studio generates the same public signing key for different keystores and certificates.

How can I extract the public signing key manually?

Answer (score 1):

The wizard generates the key based on the keystore file you provide it with. It will not change between generations of you use the same key...by default Android provides a debug keystore. Be sure to create your own keystore as you use to production and use the same key as well for when generating the .apk file (signing it).

I don't understand how extracting it manually makes a difference. You need to extract the key by following the instructions that Worklight/MobileFirst requires.